# Reduce size of cells on Monthview

Tags: javascript, html, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4, fullcalendar-scheduler

I am trying to get a full month of events view on one computer page (Full HD) to avoid scrolling left to right.

```
if  (view.type == 'resourceTimelineMonth')
{   
  setTimeout(function (){ 

    var cols = document.getElementsByTagName ("col");
    for (var i = 0; i < cols.length; i++) {
    cols[i].style="width:2px";      
    }       
        },30);  
}
```

After the calendar is loaded I am resizing the columns of the table to 2px.
It works as expected for higher columns size than 29-30 pixels.

Less than that does not result to what should be.

How to circumvent this limit ? Any idea ?

Thanks

Comment: The effectiveness of this is always going to depend on the end user's screen size and resolution, and how big they opened their browser window, and whether they're using zoom, and what the time interval is between slots in your timeline, etc. Stop worrying about it and just let them scroll, it's normal.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a workaround for those interested. Instead of trying to reduce the columns themselves I scaled down the calendar itself. You can change the scaling manually or better doing a ratio with the innerWidth of the screen.

> if (view.type == 'resourceTimelineMonth') {
> setTimeout(function ()        {
> var box =
> document.getElementsByClassName('fc-view-container');
> var box1 =
> document.getElementsByClassName('fc-scroller-canvas');
> var box2 =
> document.getElementsByClassName('fc-time-area fc-widget-header');
> var box3 = document.getElementsByClassName('fc-cell-text');
> box1[3].setAttribute('style','width:auto;');
> box[0].setAttribute('style','transform:scale(0.25,1);transform-origin:0
> center;width:6600px');
> box2[0].setAttribute('style',';transform-origin:0 center');
> for (let i=0; i< box3.length;i++) {
> box3[i].setAttribute('style','font-size:10px;transform:scale(3,1)');}
> },30);
> }

Sorry for the poor formatting, cannot seem to make the identation work...